# How to boot from a DVD on a UEFI laptop with Linux

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, dvd, bios

I've bought a Windows 8.1 Lenovo laptop last year. Then on July I upgraded to Windows 10. Yesterday I formated it and re-installed Windows 10, but it isn't activating. So I ran the Ubuntu live DVD and all worked fine.

The question is: if I wipe everything and install only Ubuntu, how will I access the UEFI bios again, in case I want to install a different distro or even go back to Windows 10?

Thank you very much!

Renato

Comment: You can access bios no matter what OS you have.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a new operating system does not change your BIOS, so booting into any installation media will always take the same procedure.

To boot to an install disk, either key into your BIOS or your Boot Menu. The Boot Menu is typically F12, and BIOS on Lenovo is typically F2. For Boot Menu, press F12 when the "Lenovo" logo appears at startup, then select your disk drive to boot from DVD. For BIOS, press F2 at the Logo screen, then find the Boot options tab.

Comment: -1 This has nothing to do with booting Ubuntu off of a DVD.

Comment: I see now, I misunderstood the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully my edit answers the question better.